# Enhance existing web app with Sencha ExtJS?

Tags: web-applications, widget, extjs

I have an existing web application which uses a standard jQuery powered datagrid, but could really do with something more fancy.

All the ExtJS examples on the Sencha website use their layout creator and how a desktop app can be replicated in the browser. I would like to know - is it possible (and feasible) to use the ExtJS components/widgets in 'normal' HTML pages, as per a standard webapp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  You can include the ExtJS library on your page, just like jQuery, and do all kinds of things -- manipulate the DOM, add/remove HTML elements on your page, insert ExtJS components anywhere within your markup, etc.

For example, if you have an element with an id of "my-ext-widget", then you can create an ext component (like a panel) and insert it in that element, like this:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    myPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        title:'Sample Panel',
        height:300,
        width:200,
        html:'This is a sample panel'
    });

    myPanel.render("my-ext-widget");
});
```

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You could also use the `renderTo` config and omit the .render() call as a separate line.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to know! I'd like to use the ExtJS datagrid component as the jQuery options, while functional, do not compare in terms of functionality or visual appearance. The data needs to be sorted server-side (due to the volume), have a search box linked to the datagrid and in addition able to be filtered by one column's value. I was under the impression ExtJS was a stand-alone RIA toolkit and couldn't be used to enhance a HTML-based webapp.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is possible and without being too invasive on your current code base. i.e. you can load you existing DOM and then do the Sencha magic after your page loads (in onReady as explained by Jonathan) for whatever you can think of (within the ExtJS boundaries offcourse).

Also, not all examples use their layout creator.

This is a perfect example of the concept you are trying to get at-
[How to create a grid from an existing, unformatted HTML table](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/grid/transform-dom.html)

Comment: Thanks amol, I'd missed that demonstration!

Comment: The new url is http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/example/grid/transform-dom.html